# How to solve a system with sin,cos?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have these systems:

$x''=\frac{-g(2m_1+m_2)\sin x-m2g\sin(x-2y)-2\sin(x-y)m_2(y'^2L_2+x'^2L_1\cos(x-y))}{L_1(2m_1+m_2-m_2\cos(2x-2y))}$

$y''=\frac{2\sin(x-y)(x'^2L_1(m_1+m_2)+g(m_1+m_2)+g(m_1+m_2)\cos(x+y'^2)L_2m_2\cos(x-y))}{L_2(2m_1+m_2-m_2\cos(2x-2y))}$

Which I want to linearize.

I have $x'=w$, $y'=z$

I get $w'=\frac{-g(2m_1+m_2)\sin x-m2g\sin(x-2y)-2\sin(x-y)m_2(z^2L_2+w^2L_1\cos(x-y))}{L_1(2m_1+m_2-m_2\cos(2x-2y))}$

$z'=\frac{2\sin(x-y)(w^2L_1(m_1+m_2)+g(m_1+m_2)+g(m_1+m_2)\cos(x+z^2L_2m_2\cos(x-y))}{L_2(2m_1+m_2-m_2\cos(2x-2y))}$

And was trying to input them into this matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\?&?&?&?\\0&0&0&1\\?&?&?&?\\\end{pmatrix}$ with $x=\begin{pmatrix}x\\w\\y\\z\\\end{pmatrix}$

Im not sure how to deal with terms like $-g(2m_1+m_2)\sin x$. I'm use to linearizing systems which have simple coefficients in front of the terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are linearizing for small movements around $x=y=0$, so that all quadratic and higher-degree contributions in $x,y,x',y'$ can be neglected. Among other things, $\sin x$ gets replaced by $x$, $\cos(x-y)$ by $1$ etc. What remains in linear terms after this pruning is
\begin{align}
w'=x''=\frac{-g((m_1+m_2) x-m_2y)}{L_1m_1}
\\
z'=y''=\frac{2g(m_1+m_2)(x-y)}{L_2m_1}
\end{align}
Note that I had to interpret some missing closing parentheses.

Comment: Did you mean $sin(x)=0$? since $x=0$?

Comment: I said "around $x=0$", or in other symbols, for $x\approx 0$.

Comment: I still don't see how you have a $-g$ term in $x''$. I get that $w'=\frac{m_2(z^2L_2+w^2L_1)}{L_1(2m_1)}$ with $x=y=0$.

Comment: Close to zero, but not zero. $z^2$ and $w^2$ are quadratic and thus do not occur in the linearization.

Comment: So I set the quadratic terms to $1$? I also don't get why $\sin x$ is replaced by $x$

Comment: Because $\sin x=x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5\mp...$, so that for small $x$ only the linear term dominates. If that does not help, replace in the original equation $x,y$ with $εx,εy$ everywhere, also in the derivatives. Then divide by $ε$ and consider the limit $ε\to 0$. This does not produce singular terms, as the origin is an equilibrium point.

Comment: I still don't see how the second equation happens since, does $sin(x-y)=0$? Because then the numerator in $y''$ should be $0$?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are small separately, then $x-y$ is also small, there is nothing more to say about that. Occasionally, the difference may be zero, but the numbers may also have opposite signs so that their sizes add.

Comment: So to linearize the system I have to take taylor expansions of the nonlinear functions and just set the higher degree terms to $1$?

Comment: Where in the world is $1$ a good approximation for some power of degree 2 or higher of a very small number?

Comment: Sorry they are $0$. But after this point I then just differentiate with respect to $x,w,y,z$ and input that in the corresponding coordinates of the matrix? And just solve as if its a regular linear system?

Comment: What I described was to avoid explicit differentiations, after all that remains is a linear system, one can directly read off the matrix entries. And yes, after that solve the linear ODE system, starting with the eigen decomposition of the matrix.